# New transaction in blockchian network

Tags: blockchain

I am new to blockchain technology and have a basic question.
I understand that in any blockchain network, if any node tries to commit something which is not in sync with other nodes , it gets rejected.Then how the new transaction is commited and validated? Who has authority to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the thing about blockchain. There is no authority that determines which block will get added to the chain. And by blockchain, I mean public blockchain.

Blockchain's typically are either public or permissioned.

### Public

Public blockchain's, such as bitcoin and ethereum work on the principle of proof of work. In layman's terms, if any participant wants there transaction to be processed, i.e added to the chain, they submit it to the network. This transaction is then processed by independent entities called miners who have to solve a computational puzzle in order to produce a valid block, which if accepted results in compensation in form of the said digital currency for the work put in by the miner. Also, the longest chain is always accepted as the valid chain.

There is absolutely no criteria or organisation that overlooks mining, meaning anybody can become a miner and start contributing. So the network is for the people, by the people, anybody can join and both submit as well as process transactions.

If the transaction is valid, that is you own the coin and are not double spending it, it will be processed by a miner. And if the block produced by the miner is accepted, so is your transaction.

### Private/Permissioned

On the other hand, in case of private/permissioned blockchain's like hyperledger fabric for example, participation and block processing is decided by a single or multiple organisations. Hence in this case, a block is processed only if it produced by a valid member and it is endorsed by nodes of all participating organizations.

Comment: Thanks Arjun :) That helps a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said "if any node tries to commit something which is not in sync with other nodes" what I get is that you are asking about the block which one node produce but rejected by the blockchain. This scenario happens when 2 nodes try to find the proof of work and one node finds it first and broadcast to the network but due to network delay (there could be other reasons too for that), and the other node didn't get the block in this way stale/uncle blocks are created. Bitcoin blockchain considers the longest blockchain and discards the other.